# Biblatex @manual - file path using understrike

Tags: biblatex, documentation, underline

I have kind of a problem with my entries for biblatex...

I want do write an entry for my bibliography like this

```
@manual{test,
    author = {{me}},
    title = {Test-PDF},
    version = {0.9},
    location = { ./project_A/ },      % that is the line in question
    location = { D:\home\project_A\ } % or this one
}
```

It does not really matter which line I am able to include, my generel problem seems to be, I do not no the correct arg for `manual` or how to use things like `location`, `eprint`, maybe `url` correct to generate a verbatim input displaying the file path of my source. 
The issue here seems to be the understrike and I dont know how to fix this. 
It is probably a stupid question and easy to answer, but I honestly did not find any online sources which were able to help me with my problem. Everything was only about change the file path of the bib-file or underlining text...
Thanks in Advance

PS:I hope there is no minimal running example neccessary, 'cause I am not quite sure how to do this for an issue within my bib-file...

Edit: even links with helpful content would be great, since it seems I dont know how to find those

Comment: `location` is not the correct field here. You probably want `file` or similar, but those are not printed by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a local file and not a URL, you could use the `file` field.

```
@manual{test,
  author  = {{me}},
  title   = {Test-PDF},
  version = {0.9},
  file    = {D:\home\project_A\},
}
```

By default `file` is ignored by the standard style, but with

```
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{file}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
```

you can get to see it.

Comment: Great, thank you. Is there any documentation on this where I can find out, why it either "cannot find the file path" or is just opening the path the tex-file is located instead of the given path by clicking on it (using `hyperref`) ?
Cause I dont really find much of a documentation for this...

Comment: @Djiwahwah By default the `file` field is treated as a URL. And it is up to your PDF viewer to recognise that this is a 'local' URL and open the correct file. I don't think there is a lot we can do.

Comment: well, that did the trick...I was using TexStudio and the integrated viewer...any usual viewer does work fine. Thanks again!